# Can I drink beer and do gym?

Tags: gym, alcohol

I heard few of my friends saying doing gym after drinking a liter beer will give a better result. Is it true?

**Does drinking beer and going to gym a good practice?**

Comment: Please try [searching for information](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=alcohol+is%3Aquestion) related to your question to avoid having duplicate questions.

Answer (score 15):

Short answer: no.  Longer answer has to do with a bunch of factors.

First, after drinking a liter of beer, you are drunk--if not tipsy.  You don't have full motor control, which means you can end up hurting yourself or others without intending to.  There's a good chance you'll get kicked out of the gym (unless you own it).

Second, alcohol dehydrates you, and to exercise properly you need to be properly hydrated.  Dehydration is made worse when you are sweating out what little hydration you have left--there's a good chance you will vomit.

Third, alcohol numbs you to pain.  That means if you do something to injure yourself, you won't know it until you really make things worse--or possibly after you are sober again.

Lastly, your friends sound like they just want to laugh at the drunk guy at the gym.  Not really a good thing.

Just don't be stupid.

Comment: "First, after drinking a liter of beer, you are drunk--if not tipsy" .... "There's a good chance you'll get kicked out of the gym (unless you own it)."  Seriously?  That's not even 3 beer... I'm not saying you are wrong, just don't assume everyone has the tolerance of a 15 year old.

Comment: I doubt that beer actually dehydrates, since it is over 90% water. See also this answer: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/11993/6547

Comment: @JensSchauder Oh god, that question links here and your comment links straight back!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Now guess how I found this question.

Comment: @Jens Schauder: it's the alcohol that dehydrates.  All alcohol dehydrates, as does caffeine, and any other diuretic.

Comment: While caffeine&alcohol does dehydrate, coffee and beer doesn't. Wouldn't be so sure about espresso and mocca though.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch as there is enough water in beer the effect of dehydration seems to be negligible, but this might depend on the amount you drink (no idea, just a guess). Anyway, drinking beer before gym is a bad idea.